# Can I list files that would be formatted with astyle?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, astyle

Does astyle have an option that would do something like:

```
"For the given list of files, list the files that *would be* modified by astyle."
```

So, basically list the files that don't conform with astyle, but don't actually change them.  I looked through the man pages and couldn't find anything helpful.  astyle creates .orig files, and I can use that info, but I'd rather not clutter the drive, even if astyle can do a purge after the fact.  I'd really would just like such an option.

Comment: It would be nice to know why I got the -1 for this question?  Feedback is good just so that I can improve my postings.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, now im good ;) Sorry though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`astyle` has a [`--dry-run` option](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_Other_Options) you can use to do this

> `--dry-run`
>   Perform a trial run with no changes made to the files. The report will be output as usual.

Comment: Nice! It's not mentioned in any `man` page I found, but recommending to check the source code was going to be my next suggestion.